# Cross Validation using Zelig package

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am using Zelig package inside R and i want to run cross-validation.

```
library(Zelig)
data(med)
z.out1 <- zelig(conflict ~ major + contig + power + maxdem + mindem + years, data = mid, model = "relogit", tau = 1042/303772)
```

I want to run a 10-fold cross vaildation, to get the confusion matrix and to calculate more measures to validate my model. How can i do it?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Please note that questions regarding use of specific software are not recommended. Please expand and generalize your question.

Comment: I understand but i found this problem very common without good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured out how to do it using Zelig.
To build a model and use it to predict on new data i need to do the following:

```
m1<-relogit(conflict~.,trainData)
y_pred = predict(m1,testData, type="response")
y_true = testData[1]
accuracy(t(y_true),t(y_pred))
```